# Calculating half-life?

Tags: logarithms

After taking a tablet, a patient has 10 units/ml in a sample of blood taken soon after, and this decreased to 6 units/ml 9 hours later.

1. What is the half-life of the tablet?
2. How long will it take decrease to 20% of its original value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming exponential decay, you model the amount of drug $N$ in the bloodstream by $N=N_{0}e^{-kt}$. You can say that $N_{0}=10$, and then you can find $k$ by solving the equation $6=10e^{-9k}$ for it.

Once you have $k$, you can find the half-life, $t_{1/2}$, by solving $5=10e^{-kt_{1/2}}$. You can solve #2 in a similar fashion.

Comment: Can I ask, what value did you get for k? Could someone walk through this step-by-step?

Comment: Let's see: $0.6=e^{-9k}\implies \ln(0.6)=-9k\implies k=-\ln(0.6)/9\approx 0.0568$.

Comment: And 28.24 hours for part 2?

Comment: If you show your work, I can comment on it. Your answer is in the right ball-park.

Comment: Sure. ln(0.20)= -0.057t. t= -ln(0.20)/0.057 = 28.24

Comment: I'd probably keep one more significant digit of $k$. I get $28.34$ hours.

Comment: So for the half-life of the tablet, I got 12.16 hours? did you find that too?

Comment: Well, I'd have $0.5=e^{-0.0568t_{1/2}}$, so $\ln(0.5)=-0.0568t_{1/2}$, and therefore $$t_{1/2}=\frac{\ln(0.5)}{-0.0568}=12.2.$$